# Does this memory stck have a virus? It is showing only 541kb but the original size is 4 gb

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage, memory-card

My  friend has a USB memory stick which is supposed to be 4 gb.

Suddenly it has changed its size after they actually tried new software for locking usb drives.

As a result the memory sticks size is reduced to 541 kb.

The memory stick is a San Cruzer USB and nothing has been copied to it as its size is greatly reduced.

Why is this and can anything be done to fix it?  Is this because of a virus?

Comment: What software did they try and what is it supposed to do?
Is it that it made a encrypted partion that needs to be unlocked in order to see it?

Comment: It's not a virus, that's what this software does. The rest of the drive drive is now locked and they are seeing the unlocked portion.

Comment: Just have your friend reverse the process.

Answer (score 1):

When you lock a USB drive, the system can no longer see the locked portion of the drive, only the free space on it. Either you unlock it, or if the data aren't important, you can use an application to wipe the entire USB drive and restore its full capacity.

### Unlock the USB drive

The same software used to lock the USB drive can be used to unlock it. This is software dependent, and the appropriate method may vary.

SanDisk FAQ - [Memory card is write protected or locked](http://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1102/kw/secureaccess/session/L3RpbWUvMTM0NDUxMzgzMi9zaWQvb1Y0YkVmM2w=)

### Wipe the USB drive

For this I use [MiniTool Partition Wizard Home Edition 7.5](http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html) *(free)*, it allows me to select the USB drive and [wipe it](http://www.partitionwizard.com/help/wipe-disk.html) fully, thus restoring the usage of its full size.

Comment: @sahil Thank you for returning and providing some feedback! I'm glad I could help. Consider accepting the answer to mark your question as solved and let future users know that this solution is useful.